# Is "be parented to" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, passive-voice, conjugation

When "parent" is used as a transitive verb, it should be grammatically correct to use "be parented by" as in the examples in the following pages:

- https://www.lexico.com/definition/parent
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.build.construction.projectelementcontainer.insertbeforechild?view=msbuild-16-netcore

However, I see some usage of "be parented to" in technical documentation or discussion, such as the following:

- https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/parent.html
- https://answers.unity.com/questions/172804/determining-what-an-object-is-parented-to.html
- https://devforum.roblox.com/t/attachment-must-be-parented-to-partinstance/613870

There seem to be more pages using this construction, but I'm not sure it's a syntactically proper expression.

Is "be parented to" grammatically correct? If so, could you explain the meaning of it (in comparison to "be parented by")?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think the terminology tag at Computer Science.SE is more appropriate. 'Grammatical' on ELU applies to standard usages, not technical jargon.

Comment: I’m again voting to close this question because I think the terminology tag at Computer Science.SE is more appropriate. 'Grammatical' on ELU applies to standard usages, not technical jargon

Comment: You can be attached to something, so why not?

Answer (score 1):

I think "be parented to" is best in this technical usage.  If *A, B* are two objects, there may sometimes be a relation between them where  *A* is called the **parent** of *B*.  When we first make that assignment, we say that we are **parenting** *A* to *B*.  After it is done, we say *A* has **been parented** to *B*.

Compare other, more common, constructions.  We are **assigning** Classroom *A* to Professor *B*.  Then *A* has been **assigned** to *B*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As for syntax, that seems to be the case in here. Semantically, however, it seems to be the opposite in the actual usages, where "A is parented to B" means "B becomes parent of A". I'll create a separate thread for this.

Comment: @Felipe1979 I see what you mean but if Autodesk uses this Lookinglass terminology and the writers of other design environments have followed suit it looks like you're stuck with it. It's now become a de facto technical term.